# HMVC reference architecture in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, architecture

We are about to implement a large web forms application to asp.net mvc3. I just read about heirarchical MVC or HMVC. I found it to be a good concept. Are there any frameworks which already supports the same?

The application is majorly a intranet with a complicated UI. We are planning to have UI like Outlook webmail like interface. Also wanted feedback on whether its good to go with MVC or silverlight can be a point of consideration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question about HMVC, I believe ASP.NET MVC does have HMVC since v2.0 in the form of **Areas**.

Couple that with **T4MVC** and calling Action.PartialX() methods and you've got yourself the next buzz-word **HMVC**.